# Generating an output with all possible interactions in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame of 19 independent variables and was looking for a way to get an output with all the possible interactions of these variables.

For example, I want the output:

E1*E2+E1*E3+E1*E4+E1*G1+E1*G2+E1*G3+E1*G4+E1*G5+E1*G6+E1*G7+E1*G8+E1*G9+E1*G10+E1*G11+E1*G12+E1*G13+E1*G14+E1*G15+E2*E3+E2*E4+E2*G1+E2*G2+E2*G3+E2*G4+E2*G5+E2*G6+E2*G7+E2*G8+E2*G9+E2*G10+E2*G11+E2*G12+E2*G13+E2*G14+E2*G15+E3*E4+E3*G1+E3*G2+E3*G3+E3*G4+E3*G5+E3*G6+E3*G7+E3*G8+E3*G9+E3*G10+E3*G11+E3*G12+E3*G13+E3*G14+E3*G15+E4*G1+E4*G2+E4*G3+E4*G4+E4*G5+E4*G6+E4*G7+E4*G8+E4*G9+E4*G10+E4*G11+E4*G12+E4*G13+E4*G14+E4*G15+G1*G2+G1*G3+G1*G4+G1*G5+G1*G6+G1*G7+G1*G8+G1*G9+G1*G10+G1*G11+G1*G12+G1*G13+G1*G14+G1*G15+G2*G3+G2*G4+G2*G5+G2*G6+G2*G7+G2*G8+G2*G9+G2*G10+G2*G11+G2*G12+G2*G13+G2*G14+G2*G15+G3*G4+G3*G5+G3*G6+G3*G7+G3*G8+G3*G9+G3*G10+G3*G11+G3*G12+G3*G13+G3*G14+G3*G15+G4*G5+G4*G6+G4*G7+G4*G8+G4*G9+G4*G10+G4*G11+G4*G12+G4*G13+G4*G14+G4*G15+G5*G6+G5*G7+G5*G8+G5*G9+G5*G10+G5*G11+G5*G12+G5*G13+G5*G14+G5*G15+G6*G7+G6*G8+G6*G9+G6*G10+G6*G11+G6*G12+G6*G13+G6*G14+G6*G15+G7*G8+G7*G9+G7*G10+G7*G11+G7*G12+G7*G13+G7*G14+G7*G15+G8*G9+G8*G10+G8*G11+G8*G12+G8*G13+G8*G14+G8*G15+G9*G10+G9*G11+G9*G12+G9*G13+G9*G14+G9*G15+G10*G11+G10*G12+G10*G13+G10*G14+G10*G15+G11*G12+G11*G13+G11*G14+G11*G15+G12*G13+G12*G14+G12*G15+G13*G14+G13*G15+G14*G15

without having to write all that out manually. I knew how to do this in the past but forgot the function I used in R.

Comment: Did you read [R generate all possible interaction variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905221/r-generate-all-possible-interaction-variables) ?

Comment: thank you! just one more question: what is the difference between .^2 and stepaic?